# Polymer 1.0: trouble with data-binding against plain Javascript object

Tags: data-binding, polymer

Using the polymer-starter-kit-1.0 (to get going more quickly) I am trying to establish data-binding against plain Javascript objects (instead of other Polymer custom-elements).

This seems to only get the initial value of the property I am binding to.

For simplicity: I added a "test" object with a Name property to the main app object,

```
  app.test = { 'Name': 'John Doe' }
```

and then added a  element on the home page like this:

```
  <h3>App Name: <span>[[test.Name]]</span></h3>
```

This will display the initial value properly ('John Doe').

When I now change the Name of that Javascript object from Javascript code directly, (on-click event of a button) as in app.test.Name = 'Jim Smith' then nothing changes in the one-way bindings.

However, if I add an input element like this:

```
  <input value="{{test.Name::input}}" />
```

Then the span element will get updated properly when text is changed in the input element.

It is as if changes made directly from Javascript are not observed by Polymer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have not used the bindings property properly.
It doesn't look like access to the polymer host object is an issue since you're using the "app" variable... which I believe is the template/dom-bind tag.

Use the host.set(path,value) to set objects and have them propagate changes.

This example should help:
http://jsbin.com/daloho/2/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

> **You must use `this.set('test.Name', newName);`.**

---

#### Explanation

The key feature (and root cause) of your problem is that you are binding to an **object path** (e.g., `test.Name` and not simply, say, just `test`) instead of a **simple property** (e.g., `test`) declared inside your `Polymer()` constructor.

Therefore, per the [documentation located here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding):

> For a **path binding** to update, the path value must be updated in one of the following ways:
>
> - Using a Polymer [property binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding) to another element.
> - Using the [set](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) API, which provides the required notification to elements with registered interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original problem was the square brackets [[ ]], which results in 1-way data binding, and I think you want 2-way data binding, so use squiggly brackets {{ }}.  I've been poring over the Polymer docs for a few days now, and am still struggling with getting stuff from 0.5 to 1.0.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do actually want one-way binding. The problem is that after the initial data retrieval it does not update anymore when the data is changed through Javascript directly, but the data refresh actually works when I update the Javascript object from a two-way bound input control!

It is as if the notifications only happen when the data change is initiated from a Polymer element. I tested the Javascript update notifications using  and Object.observe handler
and it properly reports changes done in all the scenarios.

Comment: You could also try using this.set('test.Name', 'John Doe'), maybe that will help?

Comment: Tried this, and also notifyChanges, after setting the Name property from Javascript code. Object.observe reports the changes, but the data binding does not update the controls.
It looks as if Polymer 1.0 does not support data-binding to plain Javascript view models. That would be a shame, as I could not use it then...

Comment: Found a "non-solution" by calling notifyPath from the path root:  
`function clickHandler(self, test) {  
        services.Name = 'Another Name: ' + i++;  
        self.dataHost.notifyPath('test.Name', test.Name);'  
}`  
It is a non-solution because it requires access to a polymer object.

Comment: I found a way to have the binding "orchestrated" by a "third party" which simply sets up a notification based on Object.observe, essentially wiring the Javascript object to a path down from the root polymer element: 
`Object.observe(app.test, function(changes) {
        changes.forEach(function(change) {
            app.notifyPath('test.' + change.name, change.object[change.name]);
        });
    });`
This seems to be a better (more decoupled) approach, but still nowhere near what knockout.js was giving me.

Comment: @user2101818: I'm having the same problem. So thanks for posting your solution updates in these comments. Upvoted question for that! Do you have any more recent updates to share? It's been a couple months now since your latest post. Have you found any better solutions? Are you still using Polymer?

Comment: Not using Polymer right now, but planning to have another look.
It bothers me when they say that the Polymer element is its own view model.
I would really like to see view models ( or "use case models")  stay in the Javascript domain.